# Program-O Server Error

Tags: php, program-o

Today I installed Program-O 2.6.8 on a colocation server with x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, running Apache, PHP 5.3.3, MySQL 5.6.38, PDO and cURL are enabled.

After uploading some AIML files I tried the JSON interface and received an error:
 "Something went wrong! Error = Internal Server Error"

I include the log entries and hope someone can tell me what is wrong.

Thanks

Program O has encountered an error. this may help:
 Error # 1024
 Message: Test error
 File: /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx/webspace/httpdocs/xxxxxx/programo/admin/validateAIML.php, line 21

Program O has encountered an error. this may help:
 Error # 8
 Message: session_start(): ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(/var/lib/php/session) failed: Permission denied (13)
 File: /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx/webspace/httpdocs/xxxxxx/programo/admin/index.php, line 53

[31-Jan-2018 19:39:47] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx/webspace/httpdocs/xxxxxx/programo/chatbot/core/conversation/intialise_conversation.php on line 449

Comment: "Test error" sounds like the creator of `Program-O` is deliberately putting errors into their application. The second comes from invalid permissions, and the third is a syntax error. If you've not modified any of the code, there shouldn't be syntax errors -- I'd recommend getting a new app.

Comment: The third error is what you'd get when running a PHP file containing short array syntax on a server running a PHP version lower than 5.4. In short, this code isn't compatible with PHP 5.3

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5.3 does not support short array notation, [that was brought in in PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)

Which will cause this issue:

> [31-Jan-2018 19:39:47] PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['
>   in
>   /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx/webspace/httpdocs/xxxxxx/programo/chatbot/core/conversation/intialise_conversation.php
>   on line 449

**TL;DR:** It clearly states on the docs for system-requirements: https://github.com/Program-O/Program-O#system-requirements

> Program O requires PHP version 5.3.0 or higher to function.

That means `5.4+` not `5.3.3`.

Comment: Thanks! Selecting PHP 5.6.31 did solve the errors.

Though, I guessed 5.3.3 would be higher than 5.3.0!

Comment: Why dont you use 7?